# Generating string from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have something like this:

```
counts = {"chuck" : 1 , "annie" : 42, "jan" : 100}
lst = list(counts.keys())
lst.sort()
for key in lst:
    print(key, counts[key])
```

The output would be

```
chuck 1
annie 42
jan 100
```

If I wanted to achieve this effect with a string, the string would be represented as

```
"chuck 1\nannie 42\njan 100\n"
```

Now if I wanted to accomplish this string I could try something like:

```
for key, value in counts.items():
    if value == 1:
        counts[key] = "1\n"
    elif value == 42:
        counts[key] = "42\n"
    elif value == 100:
        counts[key] = "100\n"

temp = list(counts.items())
temp.sort()
myStr = str(temp)

for char in myStr:
    if char in "[(',)]":
        myStr = myStr.replace(char,'')

finalStr = "" + myStr[0:19] + "" + myStr[20:37] + "" + myStr[38:53] + ""
```

But yeah, I think I'm overcomplicating things... What would be a better and easy way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to explain what you are after in human language, so we don't have to act as python interpreters to understand your question?

Comment: I want to generate the string above.

Comment: Do you want to be sorting by key or by value? The initial loop shows you sorting by key, but the output you show is sorted by value instead.

Comment: Ah, I want it to be sorted as keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
d = {"chuck" : 1 , "annie" : 42, "jan" : 100};
s = '\n'.join(['%s %s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])])
print(s) # 'chuck 1\nannie 42\njan 100'
```

---

```
d = {"chuck" : 1 , "annie" : 42, "jan" : 100};
s = '\n'.join(['%s %s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])])
print(s) # 'annie 42\nchuck 1\njan 100'
```

Comment: I really like this one. Thanks @Maciej A. Czyzewski

Comment: @MaciejA.Czyzewski How did I not see that! :) OK. Thanks! (btw. I did not downvote you...)

Comment: You don't need to use the list comprehension, a generator expression with work the same without the braces. Also, `operator.itemgetter` could be used instead of the `lambda` function. Finally, `format` is generally preferred over `%` substitution.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by formatting each `key, value` as the string you expect per `"{} {}".format(key, value)`

Then, join on '\n':

```
"\n".join(["{} {}".format(key, value) for key, value in counts.items()])
```

Demo:

Input:

```
counts = {"chuck" : 1 , "annie" : 42, "jan" : 100}
```

Output:

```
jan 100
chuck 1
annie 42
```

Noticed that `sorted` was a requirement, so here it is with a sort:

```
"\n".join(["{} {}".format(key, value) for key, value in sorted(counts.items())])
```

output:

```
annie 42
chuck 1
jan 100
```

Comment: Great minds think alike ... at approximately the same speed, too.  :)  I believe that it is more efficient to use a list comprehension with `.join()` rather than a generator expression.

Comment: So far, just about every answer that uses a generator expression gets the comment.  From what I've read, it's because `.join()` needs to know how much memory to allocate, so it converts the generator to a list anyway.  Of course, it would be more efficient to skip the generator part and just go straight to the list.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @zondo Indeed, on this particular example, `%timeit` says 2.4 µs vs. 3.24 µs in favor of list comprehension. I'm not sure if that's not premature optimization, though. BTW, using `*item` to unpack instead of `key, value`, seems to be marginally slower.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for checking that @arekolek

Comment: @zondo Here is the answer to comprehension vs. expression. It's great. Thought I'd share: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1832539

Comment: @idjaw: Thanks.  I'll be sure to use that link in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Concise with sorting:

```
>>> '\n'.join(sorted([k+' '+str(v) for k, v in counts.items())])
'annie 42\nchuck 1\njan 100'
```

Sorting lines instead of items. It's actually faster this way as measured by `%timeit`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky:

```
'\n'.join(["{0} {1}".format(a,b) for a,b in counts.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for concise.

```
d = {"chuck" : 1 , "annie" : 42, "jan" : 100}

'\n'.join('{} {}'.format(*item) for item in sorted(d.items()))
```